# JavaScript : can't get json elements from a Json File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file in which is stored a list of regions that I want to get dynamically using JavaScript and JQuery. here's the an example of the content of my file :

```
        {"Regions":
            [
                "Region":{
                "type":"polyline",
                "title":"Region 1",
                "strokeColor":"#000000",
                "strokeOpacity":1,
                "strokeWeight":3,
                "path":[{"lat":"21.32008096400822","lng":"79.376220703125"},{"lat":"21.524627220545295","lng":"80.48583984375"},{"lat":"20.488773287109833","lng":"80.2001953125"},{"lat":"20.427012814257385","lng":"79.552001953125"},{"lat":"20.612219573881042","lng":"79.112548828125"},{"lat":"21.32008096400822","lng":"79.376220703125"}]
                },"Region":{
                "type":"polyline",
                "title":"Region 2",
                "strokeColor":"#000000",
                "strokeOpacity":1,
                "strokeWeight":3,
                "path":[{"lat":"21.32008096400822","lng":"79.376220703125"},{"lat":"21.524627220545295","lng":"80.48583984375"},{"lat":"20.488773287109833","lng":"80.2001953125"},{"lat":"20.427012814257385","lng":"79.552001953125"},{"lat":"20.612219573881042","lng":"79.112548828125"},{"lat":"21.32008096400822","lng":"79.376220703125"}]
                }
            ]
    }
```

here's my JS code :

```
    $.getJSON( "regions.json", function( data ) {
            var regions = [];
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                    if(key=='Regions'){
                        regions=value;
                        $.each(regions,function(key,value){
                            if(key=='Region'){
                                alert(value);
                            }   
                        });
                    }   
                });
    });
```

When I test this code I get only one prompt , and I don't get the other regions .

Comment: A jsFiddle of your code would have been nice. Use a sample json you're getting in `data` in that fiddle.

Comment: A JavaScript object can't have two properties with the same name. You might want to use an array in `Regions`: `{"Regions":[]}`.

Comment: @GergoErdosi I've updated it -see the code above-  but when I test it I got no prompt :(

Comment: Because it's not a valid JSON. See Jon's answer below for an example.

Comment: JavaScript arrays (and so JSON) doesn't have key name, just values. So writing `["Region":{}, "Region":{}]` is incorrect, but `[{}, {}]` is correct: see Jon's answer

Comment: thank's to all of you for answering me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data is in wrong format, change 'Regions' to array:

```
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "type": "polyline",
            "title": "Region 1",
            "strokeColor": "#000000",
            "strokeOpacity": 1,
            "strokeWeight": 3,
            "path": [
                {
                    "lat": "21.32008096400822",
                    "lng": "79.376220703125"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "21.524627220545295",
                    "lng": "80.48583984375"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "20.488773287109833",
                    "lng": "80.2001953125"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "20.427012814257385",
                    "lng": "79.552001953125"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "20.612219573881042",
                    "lng": "79.112548828125"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "21.32008096400822",
                    "lng": "79.376220703125"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "polyline",
            "title": "Region 2",
            "strokeColor": "#000000",
            "strokeOpacity": 1,
            "strokeWeight": 3,
            "path": [
                {
                    "lat": "21.32008096400822",
                    "lng": "79.376220703125"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "21.524627220545295",
                    "lng": "80.48583984375"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "20.488773287109833",
                    "lng": "80.2001953125"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "20.427012814257385",
                    "lng": "79.552001953125"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "20.612219573881042",
                    "lng": "79.112548828125"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "21.32008096400822",
                    "lng": "79.376220703125"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```